# Macro for clicking (Mac compatible)

Tags: macos, macros, mouse, repeat

I would like to create a macro so whenever I hold a key, it will click the current position of mouse for x amount of time and releases for y amount of time.

The only ones I have found only click and pause instead of holding down the mouse button or I am only allowed to click in intervals of a tenth of a second (I would like to be able to click in a hundredth of second or even better... a millisecond). Does anybody know any good mac compatible programs out there?